# mod_rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have a basic .htaccess file in a subdirectory folder called 'support' which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([^/]*) knowledgebase.php?article=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/category/([^/]*) knowledgebase.php?category=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have changed the links in my files and removed the .php extension. When I click on a link to the rewritten url to my knowledgebase file everything works fine however I then have further links to the same file with query strings in the url eg:

$link = 'knowledgebase/category/'.$article['catid'];

The problem is once I am on the knowledgebase page links appear as:

http://www.example.com/support/knowledgebase/knowledgebase/category/2

I am pretty sure I need to use a RewriteCond to stop it rewriting but I can't figure out exactly what is required.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "links appear as," do you mean that if you click on a link, what you see is what you get in the URL bar, or if you (for instance) hover over a link, the displayed URL is what you see?

Comment: @Andrew if i click the link what I see when I hover over it as in above example is what url it directs me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this is not a mod_rewrite problem, since mod_rewrite has nothing to do with what links display on the page.  Rather, this looks like an issue with the hrefs that are actually in your link definitions (i.e., `<a>` tags).

The quickest fix might be to add something like:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/support/" />
```

within the `<head>` section of your pages.  That way, if "knowledgebase" is specified within the links, it won't show up twice in the URL for that link.

Let me know if I have this completely wrong.

Comment: that works perfectly, although I had to specify `RewriteBase /support/` in the htaccess file for it to work properly. Thanks.